# Why do we not need "else" in an if-statement if it contains "return"?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python, and I can't understand why we don't have to use `else` in cases like the one below:

```
def find_element(p,t):
     i=0
     while i<len(p):
       if p[i]==t:
         return i
       i=i+1
     return -1
```

In this code I thought I should use `else return -1` if I wanted to return -1, but it seems that python understands this without `else` like in the code above.

Comment: Why did you think you needed an `else`?

Comment: You only explictly need `else` if you are going to have code execute in that branch, otherwise the implicit behavior is equivalent to `else: pass`

Comment: (1) Describe what this is supposed to do, and *where* you thought you needed the `else`.  (2) I can infer what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure how you would do that with an `else` inserted.  Please tell us what this function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return terminates a function. Basically, if the "if" condition is satisfied within the "while" loop, the function will end. Alternatively, if the "while" loop is permitted to complete ("if" condition fails), then you force a return value. In this instance, you do not want an "else" statement if you expect to iterate through your entire "while" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the exact case you provided, it's because you're "returning" after a match. Once a function returns, no code after the return is executed meaning if you ever pass the if conditional, the method breaks out of the loop and everything, making the else unnecessary.

Essentially: you don't need an else because if your conditional ever passes the code execution breaks out of method anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need else because you if the element t is found return i yields the index, otherwise you exit loop without encountering t, return -1 will be executed. But feel free to add else pass if it make you more comfortable.

As explained above, else: return -1, is an error, with such else clause the function will only the check the first element of the list being t

Answer (score -1):

In Python the indentation decides the scope, so the `return -1` is actually outside of the `while` loop. Your code will `return -1` only if `t` is different from all `p`.